# flex will not right align my header in an Angular2 material card

Tags: flexbox, angular2-material

I can't get stuff to left and and right align on card headers via CSS. In my card header I want the the `md-icon delete_forever` to the right. I tried flex but did not work.

```
<div class="flex-container">

   <div *ngFor="let item of items | async" class="flex-items-default">


        <md-card (click)="test()" style="width:300px;height:250px">
              <md-card-header>
                    <md-card-title> 
                        <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
                        <span class="flex2"></span>
                        <span>
                          <button md-icon-button (click)="onDelete()">
                              <md-icon>delete_forever</md-icon>
                          </button>
                        </span>

                    </md-card-title>
                    <md-card-subtitle></md-card-subtitle>
              </md-card-header>
              <md-card-content>
                  {{ item.description }}
              </md-card-content>
        </md-card>

    </div>

</div>


.flex-container {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

    .flex2 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Comment: For `flex2` to work you need `display: flex` on `<md-card-title>`

Comment: I added display: flex but did not work.

Comment: Okay, well then there is something else prevent it to work. As we can't see the rendered result, a long with the relevant CSS, any suggestion will be a guess based on our own _image_ of the very same, so if you can post that we will be able to better help out

Comment: A useful tip would be to color each items background. It often helped me to _see_ what was going on and easier deal with it. Web browsers dev. tools can do that too, though I find the coloring easier

Comment: I have reverted @jonrsharpe's edit, please leave it be. We discourage excessively chatty posts, including "dudes" and "what's the dealio" - please reserve that for Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Using Flex can be a solution, but you need to understand how to use flex properties. According to [this website](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) (and to some empirical personal experience), attritutes `align-items` and `self-align` modify disposition on **cross-axis** which is, in your case, `column` as long as you defined `flex-direction: row`.

**TL;DR :** Change `flex-direction: row` to `flex-direction: column` and then css `self-align` / `align-items` will allow you to align on horizontal axis. In your case, `self-align: flex-end` on your button wrapper should do the job.